# Query on a single table in Mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following table:

OrderTable

```
City    IDCustomer   NumProd
M.      0001.          9
M.      0002.          9
M.      0001.          11
M.      0002.          7
L.      0003.          2
L.      0003.          4
```

I want to write a way to show the customer's id and his highest NumProd in each city. The output should be

```
City.  IDCustomer   NumProd
  M.    0001.        11
  L.    0003         4
```

How can I easily do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried with a subquery, but sql gives me error since there are 2 columns back in the sub

Comment: Please add all attempts to your question by editing, along with the error messages

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are looking for a basic Group by Query.

```
   SELECT IDCustomer,MAX(NumProd) FROM OrderTable GROUP BY IDCustomer;
```

The GROUP BY statement groups rows that have the same values into summary rows and is often used with aggregate functions such as COUNT(), MAX(),SUM() etc.

General syntax is :

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
GROUP BY column_name(s)
ORDER BY column_name(s);
```

Comment: There was an error in my question, fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for aggregation?

```
select idcustomer, max(numprod)
from t
group by idcustomer;
```

EDIT:

One method uses a corrleated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.numprod = (select max(t2.numprod) from t t2 where t2.city = t.city);
```

Another common method is `row_number()`:

select t.*
from (select t.*,
row_number() over (partition by city order by numprod desc) as seqnum
from t
) t
where seqnum = 1;

Comment: There was an error in my question, fixed it

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but is there any website / tutorial that you recommend do understand this type of correlated subquery? as I said it works, but I can't understand "why" it works and probably if I have to do a similar thing the next month I won't be able. Thanks